# Interprocess Communication with multiprocessing.Pipe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, ipc

I know that this is a frequent question on the forum but I couldn't find answer to my problem.

I need **two distinct scripts** to communicate via `multiprocessing.Pipe`.

I have `code1.py`:

```py
import time
#...

def code_one(pipe):
    for _ in range(100):
        pipe.send("data")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_one(parent_pipe)
```

and `code2.py`:

```py
import time
#...

def code_two(pipe):
    while True:
        if pipe.poll():
            data = pipe.recv()
            print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_two(child_pipe)
```

My problem follows:

I then need to share `parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()` but I can't manage how to use. I tried to place it in a third .py file but I couldn't import the object.

Can anyone guide me?

Edit:

1. Is it ever possible in python?
2. What other methods than `multiprocessing` may help?
3. Maybe `Pipe` isn't the tool but `Listener`s are?

Edit2:
There should be a `main.py` to start processes whose minimal case is the following:

```py
import multiprocessing

import code1
import code2

parent_pipe, child_pipe= multiprocessing.Pipe()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code1.code_one, args=(child_pipe,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code2.code_two, args=(parent_pipe,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

I don't know if this solves my problem or not. Because I want to run my program with two different arguments at the background with a shared resource:

```bash
nohup python3 my_package.py --send &
nohup python3 my_package.py --recieve &
```

in that way, the following code is used:

```py
import multiprocessing
from code1 import code_one
from code2 import code_two

import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--send', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recieve', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Create a pipe
    parent_pipe, child_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    # Spawn process for code_one
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code_one, args=(parent_pipe,))
    if args.send:
        p1.start()

    # Spawn process for code_two
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code_two, args=(child_pipe,))
    if args.recieve:
        p2.start()

    # Join the processes (optional, based on your use case)
    #p1.join()
    #p2.join()
```

Comment: Pipes are not made for distinct scripts. They are made for processes created by the multiprocessing module.

Comment: You didn't say how these 2 scripts are related nor how they were started, nor if you are using multiprocessing, nor if they are running on the same machine.

Comment: they are different modules of the same package but they are meant to run separately. there would be a `main.py` where processes are launched.

Comment: Ok, please click [edit] and add the contents of `main.py` so we can see all the details we need to assist you.

Comment: Huh? Your `main.py` starts 2 processes from one common parent, but then you show them started completely independently from two separate commands in the shell - which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You need to create connections with the multiprocessing pipe either as a parent or child from your code1 and code2 scripts. Otherwise, there's no bridge between them to communicate. Modify them like this:

- for parent:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a connection end (either parent or child)
    parent_pipe, child_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    code_one(parent_pipe)
```

- for child

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a connection end (either parent or child)
    parent_pipe, child_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    code_two(child_pipe)
```

Then you can call both of this files as connected to the `multiprocessing-pipe` with a third script:

```
import multiprocessing
from code1 import code_one
from code2 import code_two

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a pipe
    parent_pipe, child_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    # Spawn process for code_one
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code_one, args=(parent_pipe,))
    p1.start()

    # Spawn process for code_two
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=code_two, args=(child_pipe,))
    p2.start()

    # Join the processes (optional, based on your use case)
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: if i use `argparse` here to precise with which argument `p1` or `p2` should be launched, then would it work? because there will be a problem of synchronization.

Comment: you need to implement that carefully or yeah there will be a synchronization problem. You have to ensure that both processes start and establish their ends of the pipe before attempting communication. you can achieve this by creating event on both processes. check `multiprocessing.Event` module

Comment: for this, using `Manager` object is working. I finally achieved it with combining your code with a server containing a `Manager` object.

Comment: nice to hear that, wish you all the best

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone guide me?

It's impossible to communicate unrelated processes using a pipe.

> Is it ever possible in python?

No. It is also not possible in anything else.

> What other methods than multiprocessing may help?

Wikipedia lists methods of IPC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication . Pick one and use it.

For example `tmux` uses a socket file at `/tmp/tmux-<UID>/here`.

> Maybe Pipe isn't the tool but Listeners are?

No. Multiprocessing, as https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html says, is " a package that supports *spawning* processes". Your processes are separate, not spanwed from one process, this package is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. It is possible using *"something else"*. You can join two otherwise unrelated processes (without a common parent) via a `multiprocessing queue`.

Comment: `Manager` object is useful for creating a server script which shares the `Queue` object, so this is conform to what you say.